# How to add GITHUB_KEY and GITHUB_SECRET in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am running the command below in docker file.

```
CMD [“ bash”, GITHUB_KEY=“######” GITHUB_SECRET=“##########” ./script/server]
```

When I run it, I get this error message /bin/sh" 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: You _never_ do that.  Anyone who has the image can run `docker history` and trivially extract your credentials back out.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, I will make sure to just run it in my local machine and not create an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have every parameter surrounded by quotes in the CMD instruction.

`CMD ["bash", "GITHUB_KEY='######'", "GITHUB_SECRET='##########'", "./script/server"]`

Comment: I get the following message now bash: GITHUB_KEY='######' : No such file or directory even though It has accepted GITHUB_SECRET='##########'

Comment: @Zero just move those variables to ENV, so that you set them on runtime, preventing this way also the issue mentioned by @David Maze. That is, `CMD ["bash", "./script/server"]`, and you run the container as `docker run -e "GITHUB_KEY=xxxxx" -e "GITHUB_SECRET=xxxxx" container`